# No network ACL, yet my user can successfully connect to external server

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

This one's had both me and our dba scratching our heads.

We have an Oracle 11.1.0.7.0 instance, DEV, with a user who can successfully connect to our ldap server, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
  l_session DBMS_LDAP.session;
BEGIN
  l_session := DBMS_LDAP.init('ldap.host.bla.bla',389);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

We have another Oracle instance, 11.2.0.3.0 called UAT, with the same user, same set up, but when they run the above code, it raises an exception from DBMS_LDAP:

```
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
```

In both instances, if I run the following queries, no rows are returned:

```
select * from dba_network_acls;

select * from dba_network_acl_privileges;
```

To fix this problem in UAT, we've created a suitable network ACL using `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl`. Now, UAT works fine.

What's bothering us is that **this worked fine in DEV** all along, with apparently no network ACLs created. Our only theory is a bug in the version in DEV (11.1.0.7.0) but I hesitate to just leap on that as a conclusion.

We will soon be upgrading DEV to 11.2 to be consistent with the other environments, but before then, is there anything else I can check to see what difference there is between the two environments that might cause this behaviour?

(Background for those unfamiliar with ACLs: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1.php)

Comment: How was UAT created from DEV? Or was it installed separately and messed with over a period of time?

Comment: UAT was created separately. We deployed the new user using the same scripts used in DEV. However, the dba who set up DEV is no longer with the organisation; he sent our new dba some scripts (which basically just create the ACL) but he doesn't remember doing anything else differently in dev.